# How to group by the query using an attribute from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of

I have a table of `Month` with the following structure,

```
 1. MonthID (Primary Key) 
 2. MonthName
```

I have another Table of `Date` with the following structure,

```
 1. DateID (Primary Key) 
 2. Day 
 3. Month (Foreign Key, references to MonthID in Month Table)
 4. Year
```

Lastly, there's a table with the name of `Sales`,

```
 1. Date (Foreign key, references to DateID in Date Table) 
 2. SaleItem
 3. SaleAmount
```

My required query is the ***Count of Sales done for every month***

So, what I want is to get the count of Sales Table rows but group by those counts with the MonthID (that is an attribute in the Date Table) and also extract the Name of the month from the basic Month Table.

The expected outcome would be something similar to this,

| Month | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| January | 15 |
| February | 0 |
| March | 221 |
| April | 11 |

Comment: Please provide some sample data also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below query you can get the result as per above

```
SELECT "Month"."MonthName" AS "Month", count("Sales".*) AS "Sales" FROM "Month"
LEFT JOIN "Date" ON "Date"."Month" = "Month"."MonthID"
LEFT JOIN "Sales" ON "Sales"."Date" = "Date"."DateID"
GROUP BY "Month"."MonthID", "Month"."MonthName"
ORDER BY "Month"."MonthID" ASC;
```